# Google is not seeing my HTTPS website

Tags: google-search, https, http

I have a website and it is working with HTTPS, programatically when someone got to HTTP it forward him to the HTTPS version.

My issue that I see that Google Search is not seeing my pages, the website is there now for 2 months and if I searched for text copied from the website, I don't get the website in the search results.

Is there something special I should do in case of HTTPS websites to make Google index my website better?

I am using GoDaddy to manage the domain, should I do something in the domain manager?

Comment: Google indexes HTTPS websites. Please show us your _robots.txt_.

Comment: I didn't add robots.txt yet

Comment: Ok for _robots.txt_. Did you submit a _sitemap.xml_ to Google Webmaster Tools? Has your website backlinks?

Comment: Yes, submitted it and yes, some websites are linking to my website, but this is not showing in website backlinks section in Webmastertools.

Comment: In that case, I don't know why Google doesn't see your website. Please give us your website URL.

Comment: autofilemove.com

Comment: Your website is indexed by Google. Look at [this](http://www.google.com/#sclient=psy-ab&q=site:autofilemove.com&oq=site:autofilemove.com&gs_l=hp.3...3256.3935.1.4021.5.5.0.0.0.0.104.355.3j1.4.0...0.0.0..1c.1.17.psy-ab.hQ9juVu58FI&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.48705608,d.d2k&fp=de9dd272bb6c178c&biw=1600&bih=767).

Comment: yes, but if you searched for any text copied from the website, you don't get the website in the results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your website is fully copied of the `picghost.com` website. That's why you have problem on Google Search, Google returns webpages from `picghost.com` instead of your website. Google hates [duplicate content](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/66359?hl=en).

For example, two webpages with the same content: [first one](https://autofilemove.com/AccountSettings/Upgrade) and [second one](https://picghost.com/AccountSettings/Upgrade).

I think you tested your first website (`autofilemove.com`) on the other domain and now Google considers these two websites as duplicates. Remove duplicate webpages from `picghost.com` and your problems will be resolved.

Comment: picghost.com is also my website but there is nothing copied from there, they are 2 different services, how did you know that it is copied from it? is there a tool for knowing that?

Comment: I have edited my answer.

Comment: yes, i see, this is very strange, both websites are on the same server and seams that something wrong happened, thank you very much for catching this issue, but If i solved it on my server, how to ask google to refresh?

Comment: also what is the tool you used to get that the website is copied from another to make the check my self after fixing it

Comment: After problem resolved, remove duplicate webpages from `picghost.com` and submit again two _sitemap.xml_ to Google Webmaster Tools.

Comment: Type a content from `autofilemove.com` surrounded by `"` on Google and look at the website on Google result.

Comment: See if you are providing same services on two different website, i would recommend promoting single domain. If you still need to run two identical website, you can use canonical tag point to original content. There is nothing to deal with HTTPS as Google will treat http and https same.